# Difference between Properties and AllProperties in Propertybag

Tags: 2010

What is the Difference between Properties and AllProperties while working with PropertyBag in Sp2010.

Answer (score 2):

[Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.properties.aspx) returns only a subset of the metadata as a StringDictionary, while [AllProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.allproperties.aspx) returns all the metadata as a Hashtable. More details can for example be found [here](http://henry-chong.com/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-and-spweb-allproperties-spweb-properties/).

(Note: Links are to **SPWeb** members. )